# Cloud Dataprep - Multiply rows in one column based on values in other column

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I am working in Cloud Dataprep and i have a case like this:

[image]

Basically I need to create new rows in column 2 based on how many rows there is with matching data in column 1.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the scenario you want to have is: obtain all values from `column1` that match a value present in `column2`. There are many things to consider in this scenario, which you did not describe, such as: *can values in `column2` be repeated?* or *if there is a value in `column2` missing in `column1`, what should happen?* or *what happens the other way around?*

However, as a general approach to this issue, I would do the following flow:
[image]

With a flow such as this one, you **take the input table**, which as two columns like this:
[image]

In recipes `FIRST_COLUMN` and `SECOND_COLUMN` you **split both columns into different branches**, and do the necessary steps to clean each column. In `column1`, I understand nothing is needed to be done. In `column2`, I understand that you will have to **remove duplicates** (again, this is my guessing, but it would depend on your specific implementation, which you have not completely described) and **delete empty values**. You can do that applying the following transforms:
[image]

Finally, you can **join both columns together**. Depending on your needs (only values present in both columns should appear, only values present in `columnX` should appear, etc.) you should apply a [different JOIN strategy](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Join-Page_57344880#join-types). You should use a *Join key* like `column1 = column2` (as in the image), and if you choose only the second column in the left-side menu, you will have a single-column result.
[image]

Note that in this case I used an *Inner-join*, but using other JOIN types will provide completely different results. Use the one that fits your requirements better.

Comment: Just as an additional note, if you want to preserve both columns, feel free to select both in the last step. Additionally, in case you actually want to *multiply* the values, as you mentioned in the title of the question, you should not remove duplicates. This flow is just the base for your scenario, but you should be able to adapt it to your specific needs, playing around with the available options. Hope it helps!